# Android GCM Sender_ID usage

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Confused about this parameter usage.  I followed the steps for GCM setup and obtained my `senderID`.  Now do I just hard code this in my application as below?

```
intent.putExtra("sender", senderID);
```

I mean is the `senderID` the same for all installations of my client and server?  If not, how can a user setup his `senderID` when he installs the app?

Answer (score 0):

SenderId is the projectId that you create from the Google API Console page. You should use this ID to register GCM.

```
GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID);
```

After registering you can get the registrationID as follows and save it to the server.

```
String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
```

You should also get API Key from the Google API Console page and use that key to send notification to the registered devices using the registrationId that is generated in the client side.

For your question, you should create one senderID to use in the client side and one API Key to use in the server-side. All the installed clients will use the same senderId.

However, note that you can also use multiple senderId.

Read [tutorials](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gs.html) again for details.